# My gitignore doesn't work

Tags: android, git, gitignore

I tried to find solution for me but my `.gitignore` file still doesn't work

I see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore), but it doesn't help me.

This is my gitignore file:

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/android,macos

### Android ###
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/

# Intellij
*.iml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/libraries

# Keystore files
*.jks

# External native build folder generated in Android Studio 2.2 and later
.externalNativeBuild

# Google Services (e.g. APIs or Firebase)
google-services.json

# Freeline
freeline.py
freeline/
freeline_project_description.json

### Android Patch ###
gen-external-apklibs

### macOS ###
*.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

# Icon must end with two \r
Icon


# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns
.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk
```

But when I make rebild I see this in SourceTree:
[image]

All files from `libraryProjectFolder/Build` folder
()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: @1615903 I try it but it doesn't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is already tracking those files, that's why you still see them.

You should create the .gitignore BEFORE doing any commit.

You can refer to the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/3495069) if you want to untrack those files. If the project is new you could create a new repository, copy your files over and make sure you have the .gitignore file in your new repo before doing the first commit.

Answer (score 3):

I have a situation that I added a file on gitignore and for some reason that I don’t know it doesn't recognize this file on gitignore and still showing it on my working area. To ignore this file I used the command below:

```
git rm --cached myfile
```

I hope it can help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This will function for me. I didn't know what was the reason. I modified my gitignore but always appeared the files I filtered.
That's what i made:

- I untracked unneccesary files-
- Include gitignore patterns
- Commit changes.

Actually my repository works fine.